# “Unable to set CurrentPage property of PivotField class” error

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a recorded macro that should change the Business unit in a pivot table from all to European Consolidation but whenever I run the Macro I get the "Unable to set CurrentPage property" error.

My code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ECBv1.0") _
           .PivotFields("[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business]") _
           .ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ECBv1.0") _
           .PivotFields("[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business]") _
           .CurrentPage = "[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business].&[European Consolidation]"
```

Is there something I can do to fix this error?

Comment: Try removing the `&` in `CurrentPage = "[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business].&[European Consolidation]"`

Comment: @EEM That actually fixed that bug! But now its saying it is unable to get the Pivot Fields property of the PivotTable class! I thought I wouldnt have these issues considering I recorded it!

Comment: It may have to do with how you edited the macro after recording, the line in question probably was something like `"[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business]." & _ "[European Consolidation]"` when recorded, but then you edited like `"[Business_Unit].[Business Unit Hierarchy].[Business].&[European Consolidation]"'`, same could had happened with other lines.